# Табы с картинкой и ссылкой

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос с табами. При навешивание click на общий div в котором есть картинка и ссылка, переключение таба срабатывает только при условии что я кликну в пустую область где нет картинки или ссылки, а нужно что бы таб срабатывал при нажатие на любое содержание div. Без использования jQuery.
Пример:
https://codepen.io/Degaucho/pen/rgdXmo

```js
let glazingInfo = document.querySelector('.glazing_slider'),
  glazingTab = glazingInfo.querySelectorAll('.glazing_block'),
  tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('.glazing-tabcontent');

 let hideTabContent = (a) => {
  for (let i = a; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
   tabContent[i].classList.remove('show');
   tabContent[i].classList.add('hide');
   // tab[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
 }

 hideTabContent(1);

 let showTabContent = (b) => {
  if (tabContent[b].classList.contains('hide')) {
   tabContent[b].classList.remove('hide');
   tabContent[b].classList.add('show');
   // tab[i].classList.add('active');
  }
 }

 glazingInfo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target && target.classList.contains('glazing_block')) {
   for(let i = 0; i < glazingTab.length; i++) {
    if (target == glazingTab[i]) {
     hideTabContent(0);
     showTabContent(i);
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 });
```

```css
.glazing_block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.glazing_block img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.glazing_block a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.aluminum, .plastic, .french, .rise {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
} 

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="glazing_slider">
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/1.png" alt="#">
            <a class="tree_link">Таб 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/2.png" alt="#">
            <a class="aluminum_link">Таб 2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/3.png" alt="#">
            <a class="plastic_link">Таб 3</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/4.png" alt="#">
            <a class="french_link">Таб 4</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/5.png" alt="#">
            <a class="rise_link">Таб 5</a>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="row tree glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Холодное</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/img_cold.png" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 42-58 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>2600 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/img_warm.png" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-78 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Tree -->

        <!-- Aluminum -->
        <div class="row aluminum glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Холодное</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/cold.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/warm.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Aluminum -->

        <!-- Plastic -->
        <div class="row plastic glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/plastic/warm.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-70 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Plastic -->

        <!-- French -->
        <div class="row french glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Пластик</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/french/plastic.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 58-70 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>Алюминий</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/french/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 мм</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /French -->

        <!-- Rise -->
        <div class="row rise glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Алюминий</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/rise/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>Дерево</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/rise/tree.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 40-42 мм</li>
                <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 мм)</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div><!-- /Rise -->
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему в этом скрипте hideTabContent(0) скрывает весь контент, почему "0" так работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let target = event.target;
> if (target && target.classList.contains('glazing_block')) {
> ```

```
let target = event.target.closest('.glazing_block');
if (target) {
```

Код полностью:

```js
let glazingInfo = document.querySelector('.glazing_slider'),
  glazingTab = glazingInfo.querySelectorAll('.glazing_block'),
  tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('.glazing-tabcontent');

 let hideTabContent = (a) => {
  for (let i = a; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
   tabContent[i].classList.remove('show');
   tabContent[i].classList.add('hide');
   // tab[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
 }

 hideTabContent(1);

 let showTabContent = (b) => {
  if (tabContent[b].classList.contains('hide')) {
   tabContent[b].classList.remove('hide');
   tabContent[b].classList.add('show');
   // tab[i].classList.add('active');
  }
 }

 glazingInfo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let target = event.target.closest('.glazing_block');
    if (target) {
   for(let i = 0; i < glazingTab.length; i++) {
    if (target == glazingTab[i]) {
     hideTabContent(0);
     showTabContent(i);
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 });
```

```css
.glazing_block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.glazing_block img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.glazing_block a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.aluminum, .plastic, .french, .rise {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
} 

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="glazing_slider">
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/1.png" alt="#">
            <a class="tree_link">Таб 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/2.png" alt="#">
            <a class="aluminum_link">Таб 2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/3.png" alt="#">
            <a class="plastic_link">Таб 3</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/4.png" alt="#">
            <a class="french_link">Таб 4</a>
          </div>
          <div class="glazing_block">
            <img src="img/glazing/icons/5.png" alt="#">
            <a class="rise_link">Таб 5</a>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="row tree glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Холодное</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/img_cold.png" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 42-58 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>2600 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/img_warm.png" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-78 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Tree -->

        <!-- Aluminum -->
        <div class="row aluminum glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Холодное</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/cold.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/warm.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Aluminum -->

        <!-- Plastic -->
        <div class="row plastic glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>теплое</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/plastic/warm.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-70 м</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /Plastic -->

        <!-- French -->
        <div class="row french glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Пластик</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/french/plastic.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 58-70 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>Алюминий</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/french/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 мм</li>
                <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /French -->

        <!-- Rise -->
        <div class="row rise glazing-tabcontent">

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
           <div class="glazing_cold">
             <h3>Алюминий</h3>
             <img src="img/glazing/rise/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
             <ul>
               <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
               <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
               <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
               <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
             </ul>
           </div> 
            <div class="glazing_price">
                <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="glazing_warm">
              <h3>Дерево</h3>
              <img src="img/glazing/rise/tree.jpg" alt="#">
              <ul>
                <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 40-42 мм</li>
                <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 мм)</li>
                <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
                <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
             <div class="glazing_price">
                 <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
                 <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
             </div>
          </div>

        </div><!-- /Rise -->
```

Answer (score 0):

@Qwerty уже объяснил пичину. Предложу еще такой вариант, вдруг пригодится

(чуть проще выглядит):

```js
(function(){

let glazingInfo = document.querySelector('.glazing_slider'),
    glazingTab  = glazingInfo.querySelectorAll('.glazing_block'),
    tabContent  = document.querySelectorAll('.glazing-tabcontent');
    
for(let i = 0; i < glazingTab.length; i++){
  glazingTab[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(let u = 0; u < glazingTab.length; u++){
      glazingTab[u].classList.remove('active');
      tabContent[u].style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    this.classList.add('active');
    tabContent[i].style.display = 'flex';
  });
}

})();
```

```css
.glazing_block {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.glazing_block img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.glazing_block a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.aluminum, .plastic, .french, .rise {
  display: none;
}

.show {display: flex;}
.glazing_block.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="glazing_slider">
  <div class="glazing_block active">
    <img src="img/glazing/icons/1.png" alt="#">
    <a class="tree_link">Таб 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="glazing_block">
    <img src="img/glazing/icons/2.png" alt="#">
    <a class="aluminum_link">Таб 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="glazing_block">
    <img src="img/glazing/icons/3.png" alt="#">
    <a class="plastic_link">Таб 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="glazing_block">
    <img src="img/glazing/icons/4.png" alt="#">
    <a class="french_link">Таб 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="glazing_block">
    <img src="img/glazing/icons/5.png" alt="#">
    <a class="rise_link">Таб 5</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row tree glazing-tabcontent show">

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_cold">
      <h3>Холодное</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/img_cold.png" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина 42-58 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>2600 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_warm">
      <h3>теплое</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/img_warm.png" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-78 м</li>
        <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /Tree -->

<!-- Aluminum -->
<div class="row aluminum glazing-tabcontent">

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_cold">
      <h3>Холодное</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/cold.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_warm">
      <h3>теплое</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/aluminum/warm.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 м</li>
        <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /Aluminum -->

<!-- Plastic -->
<div class="row plastic glazing-tabcontent">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_warm">
      <h3>теплое</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/plastic/warm.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 58-70 м</li>
        <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /Plastic -->

<!-- French -->
<div class="row french glazing-tabcontent">

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_cold">
      <h3>Пластик</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/french/plastic.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина 58-70 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>5500 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_warm">
      <h3>Алюминий</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/french/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 60-68 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: однокамерные и двухкамерные стеклопакеты</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,63 - 1,05 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: до 5 класса</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /French -->

<!-- Rise -->
<div class="row rise glazing-tabcontent">

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_cold">
      <h3>Алюминий</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/rise/aluminum.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина 40-50 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 - 5 мм)</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>4000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="glazing_warm">
      <h3>Дерево</h3>
      <img src="img/glazing/rise/tree.jpg" alt="#">
      <ul>
        <li>Конструктивная толщина профиля: 40-42 мм</li>
        <li>Остекление: полированное стекло (толщиной 4 мм)</li>
        <li>Теплоизоляция: 0,07 м<sup>2</sup> * С/Вт</li>
        <li>Звукоизоляция: 20-27 дб</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="glazing_price">
      <p>8000 руб.кв.м.<br><span>под ключ с установкой</span></p>
      <button class="button glazing_price_btn text-uppercase popup_calc_btn">Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- /Rise -->
```

P.s. взято отсюда — [JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css/982073#982073)